# multiple forms on a page, want to submit all data in one shot

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Here is the code I have written so far:
Please help me out on how to submit twitter and google data in one shot

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<script>
function addtwitterdetails(){
    $('#formarea').empty();
    var twitterdetails="<input type='date' id='twitterdate' name='twitterdate' oninput='gettwitterdate()' required><br /><input type='number' name='twitternumber' oninput='gettwitternumber()' required id='twitternumber'><img src='images/save.png' onclick='savedata(twitterdate,twitternumber)'>";
    $('#formarea').append(twitterdetails);
}
function addgoogledetails(){
    $('#formarea').empty();
    var googledetails="<input type='date' name='googledate' required><br /><input type='number' required name='googlenumber'>";
    $('#formarea').append(googledetails);
}
</script>
<body>
Simple Test<br />
<img src="images/twitter.png" height=80px width=80px onclick="addtwitterdetails()">
```

Some text

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways I can think to do this:

1. One giant form.

All of your "mini forms" can be their own containers within a giant form, and use CSS to style it as needed. Then when you POST or submit the form, all of its data is sent in one shot. Just because a section of the page *looks like a form* doesn't mean it is. You can style anything and place *that* inside a larger form if needed.

2. javascript

you can make an Ajax call after you manually gather the data from each form's inputs. for example, in jQuery:

```
var data = {
    field1: $('#form1 input.field1').val(),
    field2: $('#form1 input.field2').val(),
    field3: $('#form2 input.field1').val(),
    field4: $('#form2 input.field2').val()
};
$.POST('/form.php', data).success(...);
```

if you need to post only forms that have been filled, or you need to post each one individually, you can put together some logic for that:

```
$('.myIcons').click(iconClick);

function iconClick(){
    $.each('form', function(){
        if ( isValid($(this)) ) { // validation logic here
            $(this).submit(); // sending logic here
        }
    });
}

function isValid($form){
    if (!$form.find('input.date').val()) return false;
    if (!$form.find('input.price').val()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

It sounds like you have some logic questions of which forms you submit vs. don't, so JavaScript is likely the more flexible/scalable method.

Comment: Here is my code. Now can you help me submitting data for twitter and google in one shot:

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForms()" />

function submitForms(){
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    document.getElementById("form2").submit();
}
```